# show the menu when the hover event icon is activated only with CSS

Tags: html, css

**Help , I can not do that when you activate the hover aparzca the rest of the div**

- I am seeking to activate the hover -law early levels appear and when you hover on the first levels appear the following
- List item

```css
body { margin: 3%; }
div.title { 
    position: relative;         
    margin-right:2%; 
    border: 2px solid orange;
    background-color:orange;
    border-radius: 2px; 
    height: 400px; 
    width:36px; 
    float: left;        
}

.title:before { 
  position: absolute; 
  content:""; 
  border-top: 6px solid white; 
  border-bottom: 17px double white; 
  height: 5px; 
  width:30px; 
  top: 4px; 
  right:3px; 
}

.title:hover:before { 
  position: absolute; 
  content:""; 
  width:auto;
  top: 11px !important; 
  left:1px !important; 
  border-left: 16px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) !important; 
  border-right: 16px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) !important; 
  border-top: 16px solid white !important;
  border-bottom: none; 
  background-color:orange;
}


.item,.desplegable {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu-option">
 
    <div class="title">
    </div>
    <input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="CiVpO4FRnoe021mD68+lxPfMwBZygSRro9kFFZbmFzG89tqDv0QuHAyxo8Nsldeh8DkoVzd9+S0N7OGQhZtazNeFsmQ2ov4iuEfVCEYiHia4PVRRBCpIs/U2HvbjpffahdVYtabrA8p/XVy4TO8bh1ToRRY=">
    <div class="item">
        <a href="/Home/Index" class="formsMenu">
            <li class="viñeta3">Inicio</li>
        </a>
    </div>
    <ul class="padre">
        <a class="desplegable" href="#">
            <li class="viñeta3 viñetablanca desplegable">Administración dt</li>
        </a>
        <ul class="request-list subnavegador viñeta3" style="display: block;">
                <div class="item">
        <a href="/Campaign/List" class="formsMenu">
            <li class="viñeta3">Campañas</li>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <a href="/Categories/List" class="formsMenu">
            <li class="viñeta3">Categorias</li>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <a class="formsMenu">
            <li class="viñeta3" onclick="getForms()">Formularios</li>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <a href="/PerformanceIndicator/List" class="formsMenu">
            <li class="viñeta3">Indicadores</li>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <a href="/Hierarchies/List" class="formsMenu">
            <li class="viñeta3">Jerarquias</li>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <a href="/Account/List" class="formsMenu">
            <li class="viñeta3">Usuarios</li>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <a href="/StrategySettings/Index" class="formsMenu">
            <li class="viñeta3">Configurar estrategias</li>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <a href="/ObjectPermissions/Index" class="formsMenu">
            <li class="viñeta3">Configurar permisos</li>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <a href="/RedisCache/Index" class="formsMenu">
            <li class="viñeta3">Administracion REDIS caché</li>
        </a>
    </div>

        </ul>
    </ul>
    <ul class="padre">
        <a class="desplegable" href="#">
            <li class="viñeta3 viñetablanca desplegable">Nuevas Solicitudes</li>
        </a>
        <ul class="request-list subnavegador viñeta3" style="display: block;">
                <div class="item">
        <a class="formsMenu" onclick="CreateRequest('56ae9c06-7114-4d2a-9f9e-0f678b3130f4')">
            <li class="viñetablanca2">Credito Nuevo</li>
        </a>
    </div>

        </ul>
    </ul>
    <div class="item">
        <a onclick="WorkList('d5fe1e3d-2e08-41c2-9c62-0c57607de500','spGetAvailableInterviewsUser',0) " class="formsMenu">
<li class="viñeta3">Mis Solicitudes</li>        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <a href="/Request/List" class="formsMenu">
            <li class="viñeta3">Busqueda de Solicitudes</li>
        </a>
    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use 'element1 ~ *' selector to select every siblings of element1 that are preceeded by this element. You should also change type of input, because you cannot change it by only CSS.

```css
body { margin: 3%; }
div.title { 
    position: relative;         
    margin-right:2%; 
    border: 2px solid orange;
    background-color:orange;
    border-radius: 2px; 
    height: 400px; 
    width:36px; 
    float: left;        
}

.title:before { 
  position: absolute; 
  content:""; 
  border-top: 6px solid white; 
  border-bottom: 17px double white; 
  height: 5px; 
  width:30px; 
  top: 4px; 
  right:3px; 
}

.title:hover:before { 
  position: absolute; 
  content:""; 
  width:auto;
  top: 11px !important; 
  left:1px !important; 
  border-left: 16px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) !important; 
  border-right: 16px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) !important; 
  border-top: 16px solid white !important;
  border-bottom: none; 
  background-color:orange;
}

.item,.desplegable, input[type="text"] {
    display: none;
}

.title:hover ~ *, .title:hover ~ * .item, .title:hover ~ * .desplegable {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu-option">
 
    <div class="title">
    </div>
    <input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="text" value="CiVpO4FRnoe021mD68+lxPfMwBZygSRro9kFFZbmFzG89tqDv0QuHAyxo8Nsldeh8DkoVzd9+S0N7OGQhZtazNeFsmQ2ov4iuEfVCEYiHia4PVRRBCpIs/U2HvbjpffahdVYtabrA8p/XVy4TO8bh1ToRRY=">
    <div class="item">
        <a href="/Home/Index" class="formsMenu">
            <li class="viñeta3">Inicio</li>
        </a>
    </div>
    <ul class="padre">
        <a class="desplegable" href="#">
            <li class="viñeta3 viñetablanca desplegable">Administración dt</li>
        </a>
        <ul class="request-list subnavegador viñeta3" style="display: block;">
                <div class="item">
        <a href="/Campaign/List" class="formsMenu">
            <li class="viñeta3">Campañas</li>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <a href="/Categories/List" class="formsMenu">
            <li class="viñeta3">Categorias</li>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <a class="formsMenu">
            <li class="viñeta3" onclick="getForms()">Formularios</li>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <a href="/PerformanceIndicator/List" class="formsMenu">
            <li class="viñeta3">Indicadores</li>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <a href="/Hierarchies/List" class="formsMenu">
            <li class="viñeta3">Jerarquias</li>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <a href="/Account/List" class="formsMenu">
            <li class="viñeta3">Usuarios</li>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <a href="/StrategySettings/Index" class="formsMenu">
            <li class="viñeta3">Configurar estrategias</li>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <a href="/ObjectPermissions/Index" class="formsMenu">
            <li class="viñeta3">Configurar permisos</li>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <a href="/RedisCache/Index" class="formsMenu">
            <li class="viñeta3">Administracion REDIS caché</li>
        </a>
    </div>

        </ul>
    </ul>
    <ul class="padre">
        <a class="desplegable" href="#">
            <li class="viñeta3 viñetablanca desplegable">Nuevas Solicitudes</li>
        </a>
        <ul class="request-list subnavegador viñeta3" style="display: block;">
                <div class="item">
        <a class="formsMenu" onclick="CreateRequest('56ae9c06-7114-4d2a-9f9e-0f678b3130f4')">
            <li class="viñetablanca2">Credito Nuevo</li>
        </a>
    </div>

        </ul>
    </ul>
    <div class="item">
        <a onclick="WorkList('d5fe1e3d-2e08-41c2-9c62-0c57607de500','spGetAvailableInterviewsUser',0) " class="formsMenu">
<li class="viñeta3">Mis Solicitudes</li>        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <a href="/Request/List" class="formsMenu">
            <li class="viñeta3">Busqueda de Solicitudes</li>
        </a>
    </div>

</div>
```